# Database Design for Document Library

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-modeling

We are attempting to built the Document Library (File Management) as apart of our core apps. It starts with simple one obviously.

I need a feed back regarding the database design for this particular module.  Initial Design:

### File table:

- FileID
- FileGUID
- TenantID
- FileName
- FileDescription
- FileImage
- FileSize
- FileExtension
- ContentType
- CreatedUTCTimeStamp
- CreatedIP
- CreatedBy

### Folder table:

- FolderID
- FolderGUID
- FolderName
- FolderDescrption
- CreatedUTCTimeStamp
- CreatedIP
- CreatedBy

### FolderFiles table:

- FolderID
- FileID

Any input that will be great. Possibly in the future to have workflow, permission(s), etc etc

Comment: Not sure how you're going to mark an answer for this question, but based on the acceptance percentage - you don't seem to do that anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Add LastUpdatedTime/LastUpdatedIP/LastUpdatedName to all tables
- Consider a FolderFolders table
- Break the Files table into a Documents table and a Files table.  As the system evolves there is a good change that you may add the ability to store content that are not files.
- Do not treat folders as a sub-class of file.  These are two separate concepts and combining them makes evolving the system difficult.
- Be careful if you implement the Unix link concept.  Most Windows users are used to folder security securing files as well.  In your system, if a file can be stored in multiple folders, the file could be secured in one folder, but unsecured in another.

Comment: What is the purpose of FolderFolders table in this context?

Comment: You mentioned about: "As the system evolves there is a good change that you may add the ability to store content that are not files." What sort of content is that? Can you give an example for this?

Comment: The FolderFolders table allows the system to implement a folder hierarchy such you see in Windows Explorer.
Once a system has enough content, users will want/need to implement a hierarchy in order to help manage the complexity.

Comment: I'm thinking of XML.  Any content can be saved as a file.  However, it is very difficult to report on.
By storing XML in the database one can use XML extensions to SQL to query the content and combine it with relational data.
The other option would be any type of custom form for data entry.  That information would be stored as a document stored as relational records.  Implementing workflow could result in processes where data entry is performed and the data stored in the database where it could be reported on.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out commercial solutions (eg, [Oracle Content Management](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/content-management/index.htm)) and open source solutions (eg, [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)).  You really don't want to start from scratch on this one if you can avoid it.

A couple of points on your schema though ...

- You probably want to treat Folders as just a kind of File that can contain other Files.  This allows you to have Folders in Folders, which is quite beneficial.  For this you could omit the Folder table and just have a boolean field (Y/N) in File that says if this File is a Folder.  There would be another File field that has the FileID of its containing Folder File.  Your schema already points out the strong similariry of File and Folder.  (But hierarchies like this are hard to model efficiently in RDBMSs.)
- There could be a default FileImage for each FileExtension, if FileImage is null.  This would require another table keyed on FileExtension and also containing the FileImage.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how UNIX file systems are designed. They have a number of *inodes*, which have no name on their own. All files, directories, symbolic links are a sub-type of *inode*. They all get their names only from the directory listing. This allows you do use the same file in multiple directories/using different names (this is called *hard link* in UNIX terminology).

Answer (score -1):

[Didn't someone design this database before?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinFS). WinFX... no... WinZS... no... Got it. **WinFS**.

Comment: I don't think this is technology is open though. I rather have something that integrate with the app that I have.